# Apache not serving website

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

My website was running perfectly. Today I found that someone had rebooted the server (which is a virtual machine) and the website is not working from that time.
Apache is set to run automatically, and it is running.
I tried to restart apache and the server again and to turn the firewall off, but still the website is not working and the browser tells me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Apache error log gives these messages when I restart apache and try to open the website:

```
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.275157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.562277 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.563254 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2f mod_wsgi/4.4.22 Python/2.7.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.563254 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00456: Server built: Dec  9 2015 12:21:09
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.563254 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24'
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:32.563254 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4928
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:33.040811 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 4928:tid 364] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 12 16:14:33.275195 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4928:tid 364] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:04.407249 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1688:tid 360] AH00362: Child: Waiting 30 more seconds for 7 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:34.699426 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1688:tid 360] AH00362: Child: Waiting 0 more seconds for 7 worker threads to finish.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:34.800016 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1688:tid 360] AH00363: Child: Terminating 7 threads that failed to exit.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:34.800016 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1688:tid 360] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:47.162795 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4928:tid 1000] c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\skimage\\filter\\__init__.py:6: skimage_deprecation: The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed to `skimage.filters`.  This placeholder module will be removed in v0.13.
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:47.162795 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4928:tid 1000]   warn(skimage_deprecation('The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed '
[Tue Apr 12 16:15:47.162795 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 4928:tid 1000] 
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.326490 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00424: Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.452471 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.452471 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2f mod_wsgi/4.4.22 Python/2.7.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.452471 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00456: Server built: Dec  9 2015 12:21:09
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.452471 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache24'
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.453448 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1356:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3708
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:19.922216 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3708:tid 360] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:21.297269 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3708:tid 360] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:22.298284 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4928:tid 364] AH00363: Child: Terminating 57 threads that failed to exit.
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:22.298284 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4928:tid 364] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:22.773888 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3708:tid 984] c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\skimage\\filter\\__init__.py:6: skimage_deprecation: The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed to `skimage.filters`.  This placeholder module will be removed in v0.13.
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:22.773888 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3708:tid 984]   warn(skimage_deprecation('The `skimage.filter` module has been renamed '
[Tue Apr 12 16:17:22.773888 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3708:tid 984]
```

What may cause this problem? or What else I can check?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your network connection to the VM has problems.  Try to telnet into it on port 80.  You can find instructions to do this with Google."